# General Session Management and common time out

Tags: c#, session, session-state, session-timeout, session-cookies

What is general Session timeout for any web application? Whether it should be of some minutes if i remain idle after login ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default is usually 20 mins after the last page request. Another way to think about it is you are giving users 20 mins to do something before their session expires.